# Google Analytics capturing the test site data and prod instead of only prod data

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics to track my prod site data. Prod url is on the lines of abc.def.com. I have added abc.def.com as properties in Analytics. I have a test site on the lines of test.abc.def.com. I have added the Google script code to both test and prod sites.

Even though the Google Analytics app is directed towards abc.def.com, the Analytics is tracking the values from the test site test.abc.def.com. How do I restrict the analytics data to monitor only prod site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a filter on your Google Analytics View.

Select the GA View >> "Admin" >> "Filters" (right column "View") >> "Add Filter"

Exclude the test-hostname:

[image]